# Copying file with its commits to another remote

Tags: git, merge, git-remote, git-checkout, git-cherry-pick

I am trying to copy the commits of one file to another remote branch. The flow is described in the picture below:

[image: flow]

The important part is that I would like to keep the history of the commits (so not one merge commit without a reference to who made the changes in Remote 1) when "copying" the file from one remote to another.
Also, I don't want to copy other files as well, so only the file I want.

I have tried a git checkout but once I committed the merge, and pushed this to Remote 2, the commits from Remote 1 were gone and only the merge commit was there.

Could git cherry-pick be the answer here?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like git cherry-pick is indeed what you need (provided that indeed no commit affects both file 1 and file 2)

In your case, it would look something like:

```
git checkout <some-branch from remote 2 on which you wish to push the changes>
git cherry-pick <sha F2C1> <sha F2C2> <sha F2C3>
git push
```

where `FiCj` means `File i Commit j`

**Edit:**

In case the condition that no commit affects both F1 and F2. This is what you could do:

```
git checkout <some-branch from remote 1 from which you get the changes>
git rebase <some-branch from remote 2 on which you wish to push the changes> -- interactive
```

then you get a text editor letting you choose commits. 
Mark all commits only affecting F2 as `pick`, those only affecting F1 as `skip` and the others as `edit`.

You will be able to edit each individual commit. Every time, execute the following

```
git checkout HEAD~1 F1
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

What you are doing is: for every dirty commit (editing both files) checkout F1 as it was before teh commit, and commit it that way (i.e., undo changes to F1)

Comment: Would it be possible to overcome the prerequisite that no commit affects both file 1 and file 2?

Comment: Nice, but how can you do the interactive merging programmatically? I would like to automate all this if possible.